# Frustum culling with an octree: one AABB per bone or one AABB per object?

Tags: 3d, directx, culling, frustum, octree

I've constructed an octree for use in frustum culling. The question is, should I insert an AABB for each bone of each object, or just the one AABB for the object?

Comment: Bones? If the object is animated using bones then you would need to get the 'biggest' AABB possible (for all animations) and use that one. Recalculating boxes according to the new bone size/pos/rot and moving inside the octree each frame will most probably be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really just use one AABB for most objects.  You could always check the object twice, first on a per-object basis and then on a per-bone basis if you want the extra precision.